# Collision in python with turtles

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am working on making it so when two turtles touch the player controlled one will hide and the game will end

```
if playerone.xcor, playerone.ycor = zombie.xcor, zombie.ycor():
```

can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
if playerone.distance(zombie) < 10:
```

Pick a proximity number based on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should make a sort of "radius" that senses when they're close/touching.

For example:

```
while True:
   # add your movement code here
   playerx = playerone.pos()[0]
   playery = playerone.pos()[1]
   zombiex = zombie.pos()[0]
   zombiey = zombie.pos()[1]
   if playerx > zombiex - 10 and playerx < zombiex + 10:
      if playery > zombiey - 10 and playery < zombiey + 10:
         playerone.hideturtle()
         break
```

We're using 10 as the collision area, so when playerone's position is within 10 pixels of zombie's position, playerone will hide and the loop will be broken.